# Algorithm to calculate score/rating based on multiple performance based indicators

Tags: algorithms, scoring-algorithm

First of all,  have to confess that my math skills are not the best and i would appreciate if you could please keep your response as simple as possible (preferably in layman's term).

I'm trying to create a scoring system for some performance reporting that I'm currently working on. There's a lot of data to go through, so I thought that a way I can help with when navigating the data would be to create a system that scores our campaigns (some type of efficiency indicator) based on a couple of variables/indicators (listed below). This would allow us to promptly identify and prioritize low performing campaigns. I would appreciate if you could please help me create an algorithm that could solve for this issue.

**List Variables/Indicators:**

1. **Opportunities (This is an amount):** This represents the amount of times a campaign has the chance to serve an impression to a user.
2. **Ad% (This is a percentage):** This percentage represents the amount of time an impression is waiting to be loaded after an "Opportunity" occurs. The **highest** this number the better it is.
3. **Fill% (This is a percentage):** This percentage represents the amount of time an impression was actually displayed. The **highest** this number the better it is.
4. **Margin (This is an amount):** This represents the campaign's profitability.The **highest** this number the better it is.
5. **Error% (This is a percentage):** This percentage represents the amount of time an error was generated, which prevented an impression from being displayed. The **lowest** this number the better it is.

Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide to help.

Comment: Fill% seems to incorporate Ad% and Error% already. Margin doesn't seem to be directly connected to the others so it's value has to be considered separately. I would suggest just looking at Impressions = Fill% $\times$ Opportunities and at Margin.

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, Thanks so much for your help. Can you please explain what you meant by "Opportunities and at Margin"? I understand that you are suggesting that I calculate "Fill% X Opportunities", but I'm not quite understanding what to do with "Margin". In regards to Margin, Margin should be considered in the equation, given that all the previous factor will affect the total amount represented by our profitability/margin. Also, I what if I were to reconsider my % variables/indicators and would include the actual amount of how they are calculated?

Comment: You said a couple of indicators. It seems to me that the most useful indicators you can get out of your list are going to be the number of filled opportunities (Fill% $\times$ Opportunities) and the Margin (the "at" was a typo from my failing to delete all of an earlier wording during a revision). I don't know how to most usefully combine these into a single rating. There just isn't enough information given to even guess at that.